# How to make a log system for tornado

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I've read the documentation: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/log.html

But I still don't know how to make a suitable log for my server, which is built with tornado.

For now, I need such a log system:
It can log everything with time format, and for each day it create a new log file.

It seems that `TimedRotatingFileHandler` is what I need but I don't know how to use it with tornado.

Comment: It might be easier for you to just write a logrotate configuration file for your application.

Comment: @Blender Does logrotate have any major advantages over logging modules `RotatingHandler` or `TimeRotatingFileHandler`? I have no experience with logrotate but from the quick read of the documentation, all these seem to be doing exactly same things.

Comment: @xyres: It handles most common log rotation operations in a single line, like compression, deleting old logs, renaming, etc. It's what a lot of software uses. It's not as powerful as something written from scratch in Python, but I've never needed anything beyond compressing logs daily and removing anything older than a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tornado logging streams are just standard loggers from the "logging" python module.

There is nice tutorial on the python website https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial

As per how to set the handler (same tutorial)
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers

Comment: can you write me an example of setting tornado logger?